# What is the Reconstructionist theology notion of G-d?

Tags: sources-mekorot, theology, heterodox

I would like to know more about the Reconstructionist theology. What books would be good to know more about this movement, stressing the objectives and consequences of its altered understanding of G-d?

I am asking since I have read that this movement attempts at preserving Judaism while excluding theism at the same time. I was wondering how then do they substitute the traditional understanding of a notion of "G-d"? From what I have read the term is still meaningful there as opposed to for example the Humanist movement.

#### Edit summarry:

I have switched from a bit too general question on the Reconstructionist theology book sources to a concrete request for the readings on the movement's understanding of G-d.

Comment: Could you let me know what is wrong with my question instead of just voting it down?

Comment: It's off-topic.

Comment: (Personally, I didn't down-vote. But that's an old argument: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59369/i-dont-like-to-downvote-newbies-am-i-being-too-soft)

Comment: I'm not sure it's off topic, per http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1298/how-should-we-handle-pluralistic-posts as it is asking for sourcable material, kinda. (ie it's still an opinion question about which book is better, but we take those for orthodox movements too.)

Comment: How is it off topic?

Comment: I don't think it's off-topic.  It feels a little general, though.  Is there any more context you can add?  (What have you already read, what leads you to ask the question, etc?)

Comment: @DoubleAA, we have two almost-equally-high-voted answers there, so I'm not sure what standard you're going by in your comment here. According to one, this question is off-topic. According to the other, it's not.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I have just changed my question in order to make it less general.

Comment: @msh210 I don't see how it could be stated and clearer that these are not MT sources.

Answer (score 4):

There's a pretty good list [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructionist_Judaism#References).

For reference:

> "Platform on Reconstructionism", *FRCH Newsletter*, Sept. 1986, pages D, E
>
> *Exploring Judaism: A Reconstructionist Approach*, Rebecca T. Alpert and Jacob J. Staub, The Reconstructionist Press, 1988
>
> David Griffin's article in *Jewish Theology and Process Thought*, Ed. Sandra B. Lubarsky and David Ray Griffin, State University of New York Press, 1996
>
> Louis Jacobs *God, Torah, Israel: Traditionalism Without Fundamentalism*, Hebrew Union College Press, Cincinnati, 1990;
>
> *Judaism As a Civilization*, Mordecai Kaplan, The Jewish Publications Society, 1994
>
> Mordecai Kaplan "The Meaning of God in Modern Jewish Religion", 1962

Comment: Would you recommend any of these personally? Is it good to start from Mordecai Kaplan or has the movement changed too significantly since his writings?

Comment: See the updated question.

Comment: @infoholic_anonymous I've never read any of these, though from conversations with Recon Jews, I get the sense that Kaplan is still well-regarded in the movement.

Comment: @infoholic_anonymous Moredecai Kaplan is still a well regarded author, however I think you will find that the movement has changed significantly since his writings.  However, everyone still likes to claim that their significant change is just an extension of what he wrote.

Comment: @avi could you please sketch some examples of what has changed or where could I get such an information?

Comment: @avi Is that any different than any other movement of Judaism?

Comment: @infoholic_anonymous Mordecai Kaplan spoke more about the tradition and how the Jewish people interacted as a group, today there is more talk of the individual and how they relate to societies and cultures.