# Is Reconstructionist Judaism essentially atheistic?

Tags: theology, heterodox

Is Reconstructionist Judaism essentially atheistic? It seems that they treat Judaism as mere "culture" that they should cherish.

In fact, that's what atheism's view is on most religions: that there isn't really God but people believe in him anyway as a strategy to get along with others. Things like making better society, upholding morality, uniting people against common enemies, properly aligning ones' interests to common goals etc.

Am I missing something?

Some quote from wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructionist_Judaism

> Not all of Kaplan's writings on the subject were consistent; his
>   position evolved somewhat over the years, and two distinct theologies
>   can be discerned with a careful reading. The view more popularly
>   associated with Kaplan is strict naturalism, à la Dewey, which has
>   been criticized as using religious terminology to mask a nontheistic,
>   if not outright atheistic, position.

Comment: Atheism doesn't *have* a view on most things.

Comment: I mean atheism view on most religions. Sorry :)

Comment: That's far from the entirity of Reconstructionist thought and is worded rather offensively (that Reconstructionists think others use the concept of G-d exclusively to manipulate people is ridiculous).  I really think this question will not get a decent answer here as it's largely an Orthodox crowd, but I suggest reading http://www.keddem.org/foot/99-06.html

Comment: for further reference http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18790/what-is-the-reconstructionist-theology-notion-of-g-d

Comment: I changed the word "manipulate others" to "get along with others". It's the same thing essentially, but it does have different connotation, which is something I often forget. Obviously people often honestly think that their morality is positive while it's often just positive for them and not necessarily for others.

Comment: Obviously I want people to feel positive about themselves, and hence should use words with positive connotation. I sometimes forget that. Where's my manner. Sorry guys :) When I said manipulate, I actually mean in a neutral rather than negative way. I mean to make people benefit you. That may or may not benefit others. Quite often it's by benefiting others actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in reconstructionist Judaism which explicitly claims that god does not exist as a function of its theological underpinings. While, according to this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructionist_Judaism) entry, some of the movement's founder's ideas seem to lead to his holding a position in line with atheism, some do not. I would surmise that there are individuals who subscribe to the ideas of RJ and are also atheists, and there are those who subscribe to it and are not. It isn't part of the platform of the movement and adopting the tenets of the movement don't require taking the atheist position.

Comment: there are plenty of atheist Orthodox Jews, too.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman That depends how you define Orthodox

Comment: I have been to some Reconstructionist Shabbat services and examined their siddur.  God is very much a part of what I saw.  *Chosenness*, on the other hand, has been largely eliminated (e.g. they don't say "asher bachar banu..." in the torah blessing, but I don't remember what they replaced it with).

Comment: @MonicaCellio I've heard "asher bachar banu _im_ kol ha'amim"

Comment: @Michoel, interesting!  A Reconstructionist guy sometimes comes to our weekday minyan and he says something different.  I'll try to remember to ask him what it is next time I see him (b'li neder).

Comment: I thought they would stress the chosenness and get rid the God part. I guess I was wrong.

Comment: I asked our Reconstructionist visitor this morning.  He says "asher bachar banu l'avod ato", but he told me that if he's visiting an Orthodox congregation he'll use *im* kol ha'amim instead (as @Michoel said).

Comment: @MonicaCellio I've heard (and now [seen](http://dorsheitzedek.org/sites/default/files/managed/Torah%20Blessings%205-3-12_1.pdf) (pdf)) "***asher kervanu laavodah** v'natan lanu et Torato*"

Answer (score 0):

Reconstructionist Judaism is pretty atheistic, yeah. Its founder, Mordecai Kaplan, rejected the idea of a supernatural God or a supernatural anything. He defines God as the force within us to effect our own salvation.

Comment: Hello Jordana, and welcome to Mi Yodeya. You could make this answer more valuable by adding a source for Mordecai Kaplan's opinions. I hope to see you around the site!